# My spark code suddenly failed with "A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection"

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark, hive, derby

My spark code run (even unit test of some method) suddenly failed for the

```
ERROR [BoneCP-pool-watch-thread] (PoolWatchThread.java:118) - Error in trying to obtain a connection. Retrying in 7000ms
    java.sql.SQLException: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
            at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.setReadOnly(Unknown Source)
            at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.setReadOnly(ConnectionHandle.java:1324)
            at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.<init>(ConnectionHandle.java:262)
            at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolWatchThread.fillConnections(PoolWatchThread.java:115)
            at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolWatchThread.run(PoolWatchThread.java:82)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
            at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
            ... 13 more
    Caused by: ERROR 25505: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
            at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericAuthorizer.setReadOnlyConnection(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.setReadOnly(Unknown Source)
            ... 8 more
```

This issue suddenly happens and I am using java spark/mysql. This should has nothing to do with my local db. Because I tried java code to directly write to db and it succeeded. Please help?

**UPDATE**:
I googled online and then find there is a folder metastore_db under my code directory (I actually found a couple of db.lck files - 1 in my home folder, 1 in spark bin, 1 in the code folder). Then, I follow some online answer to go inside and change the db.lck file's owner and right (777). Then, run the code again. Now, I got the following error and found the file was changed back to 644.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Database 'metastore_db' not found.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver20.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:361)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:501)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:298)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1187)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:204)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:249)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:327)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive(HiveContext.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.setConf(HiveContext.scala:441)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.defaultOverrides(HiveContext.scala:226)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:103)
        at com.aktana.api.command.DSESparkDriverCommand.run(DSESparkDriverCommand.java:317)
        at com.aktana.api.command.DSESparkDriverCommand.run(DSESparkDriverCommand.java:156)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
        at com.aktana.api.command.DSESparkDriverCommand.run(DSESparkDriverCommand.java:170)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:74)
        at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:89)
        at com.aktana.api.AktanaService.main(AktanaService.java:675)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Database 'metastore_db' not found.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
        ... 97 more
------

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolUtil.generateSQLException(PoolUtil.java:192)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:422)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:501)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:298)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1187)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
        ... 69 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Database 'metastore_db' not found.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver20.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:361)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
        ... 81 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Database 'metastore_db' not found.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
        ... 97 more
```

Comment: have you checked if the server is running at all?

Comment: @nbk, which server you are referring to? I ususally run spark-submit for the job. As you asked, I ran `spark-submit --status` and then, got following

"Error: Missing argument for option '--status'.

Usage: spark-submit [options] <app jar | python file> [app arguments]
Usage: spark-submit --kill [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit --status [submission ID] --master [spark://...]". So I assume this means the spark server is running.

Comment: you need to check the mysql server, because it  can not connect

Comment: @nbk, mysql server is fine. Because my other java code can write to the same db tables.

Comment: It is good that you found, I hope others will profit from your answer

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems caused by a spark code unit testing was added during the fat jar build.
To fix it, all I did is deleting the metastore_db folder under the code directory.